# MinGW / MinGW64 Linking and Dependency on `msvcrt.dll`

Tags: windows, linker, mingw, mingw-w64, msvcrt

I am coding for WinAPI in MinGW

One thing I still have not fully understood is the VC redistributable, 
I got a whole pack of question to it

Some say that such programs will need the `msvcrt.dll`

1. is the same library needed for bot c++ and c compilation?
2. is this available on all targets of clients?
3. must I redistribute it? can I redistribute it?
4. can I easily get rid of this external dependency?
5. is there other compiler that will allow me not to carry such unpleasant external dependency? (as I vaguely remember hearing that something is wrong with it - it is probably not core system lib, I heard, or it is not free to use and redistribute the library)

I see something wrong is here as I would like to produce no dependency small exes only calling the system WinAPI and if I use 
some like C standard library functions functions I would prefer it economically and statically compiled in, not any third-party dependencies

Comment: MinGW depends on the pre-installed msvcrt.dll, available on any Windows machine.  You can't distribute it.  You can't replace it, it is protected.  This is indeed a significant liability and there is no viable open source alternative.  Also what is seriously hampering Clang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. MSVCRT.DLL contains mostly the C runtime, and MinGW can only use the C part. C++ binary code cannot be used across compilers generally.
2. It depends on your "target". It is available from Windows 2000.
3. No. No. It is Microsoft-proprietary code, and every Windows version has a slightly different version.
4. No. I am not aware of a mature alternative C run-time DLL.
5. You do not need to worry about the dependency, as it is available everywhere. (Do notice that it is not really a great run-time, esp. regarding multi-byte characters.)

Microsoft compilers can link with "static" libraries so that the resulting executable depends only on system DLLs like kernel32.dll, user32.dll, etc. MinGW cannot do this (yet).

EDIT: A concise description of the MSVCRT.DLL problem is [here](https://yongweiwu.wordpress.com/2016/05/27/msvcrt-dll-console-io-bug/).

Comment: Good Answer. Anyway can you say what you mean by "is not really a grat run-time", you mean is inefficient ? That is a think i worry.. If so does some codes compiled with mingw be inefficient for this reason?

Comment: PS PS this clarifyes some things to me (great thanx) though not all, I not see what compiler do except chanelling calls to msvcrt.dll and probably he is doing something (for example if he is doing some static linking to or it is just calls to msvcrt.dll that covers full clib (?) 
Yet also this builtin stuff which must be done outside msvcrt.dll but is unpleasently vague/obscure)

Comment: @user2214913 As I mentioned, there are issues regarding multi-byte characters. See a discussion here: http://mingw-users.1079350.n2.nabble.com/MinGW-and-Non-English-Locale-on-Windows-7-td6503997.html. MinGW uses the MSVCRT runtime for all basic C functions, except functions that are not supported by the Microsoft run-time. In that case, there are MinGW-specific libraries like libmingwex.a.

Comment: Does the answer hold for `MinGW64`? I assume it is.

Comment: @Royi Yes (I suppose you meant MinGW-w64).

Comment: Is there any development regarding being able to link static version?

Comment: @Royi Nothing I am aware of. You can ask on the mailing lists.

Comment: [New link](https://mingw-users.narkive.com/1O2fDTqf/mingw-and-non-english-locale-on-windows-7) for the comment above. Also see [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/The%20case%20against%20msvcrt.dll/), and note that microsoft is [really against](https://web.archive.org/web/20160410051513/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140411-00/?p=1273/) linking to the OS-provided runtimes. MinGW64 should now support the new UCRT too though.

Answer (score 2):

According to the MS White-paper here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13350

you can redistribute certain parts of the Visual Studio components.

> Some software, such as the Microsoft .NET Framework, can be
>   distributed. Components of software products included in MSDN
>   subscriptions that can be distributed (either within an application or
>   as separate files) without royalty are identified in the REDIST.TXT
>   file associated with the product. Components that can be distributed
>   to non-Microsoft platforms are identified in the OTHER-DIST.TXT file
>   associated with the product. Code identified as distributable that has
>   the extension .lib cannot be directly distributed; it must be linked
>   into the application. However, the resulting output can be
>   distributed.
>
> You may also:
>
> - Modify and distribute source code and objects for code marked as “sample” or “Code Snippet”.
> - Distribute the unmodified output of Microsoft Merge Modules for use with an application's .msi file.
> - Distribute the MDAC_TYP.EXE file containing core data access components (such as the Microsoft SQL Server OLE DB provider and ODBC
>     driver).
> - Distribute the object version of C++ libraries (Microsoft Foundation Classes, Active Template Libraries, and C runtimes).

MS also produces a redistributable package specifically for the purpose of developers: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40784

So, to answer your questions:

1. Yes. Although it is "purely C", it contains fundamental functions that are used by the C++ part of C as well, such as file I/O, time and date functions, math functions, and so on.
2. Within reason. See link above.
3. No, yes. As described above: You may choose to just say to customers "you need to download an install this package", but the license should allow you to distribute it free of charge with your product.
4. Depends on what you call "easily" and exactly what parts of the library your code uses. Some functions may be easy to replace, others not so - but it's not easy in the sense of "yes, just go do http://www.example.com/msvcrt.dll-plugin-replacement" - it would require coming up with some replacement code. The reason MinGW DOESN'T come with its own C library is that it's not entirely trivial to write a replacement for ALL of the windows functionality that you may need here...
5. See above - if it was easy, someone would have done it. There MAY be some compilers out there that come with their own library, but it's probably not a free-of-charge and free to distribute one (I'm not aware of any product that doesn't rely on the MSVCRT.DLL - but it's not impossible that one exists)

Comment: And what this dll covers? Is it clib or something more maybe? what If this is inefficient old crap, Is this actualised? It contains probably fpu code like sin so probably eficiency of thi matters a bit? strange that mingw cannot just static link the needed clib functions

Comment: or maybe it is only a part of c-lib implementation and part of clib is statically linked too?

Comment: The redistribution package that I posted a link to is the same library that you get when you install visual studio. It is neither more nor less efficient in the redist package than if you tell your customers to install Visual Studio - except that the Visual Studio product obviously is many times larger as it comes with all manner of other files that are not redistributable. And I have no idea why MinGW does not allow/support static linking to the MS library.

Comment: ms has a large variety of this ms vc++ redustribuables (2005, 2008, 2010) and many games fire installer to it (its a mess imo) mingw seem to link yet to some older one which maybe is part of winxp and above not sure.. I mostly wonder what exactly this is is it just whole clib implementation contained in dll?

Comment: Yes, it would be the C library in a DLL. How would you do it then? If you can come up with a better solution, I'm pretty sure that the MinGW and others are happy to listen - however, there are some fairly clever people within that group, so my guess is that there is no EASY solution.

Comment: Do what? IMO it would be better if mingv could statically linked parts of clib, or yet have its ovn version of clib.dll (but the stsatic part is more needed)

Comment: Linking statically does produce rather large executables. When I did this for a simple hello-world example on Linux, the executable is about 800KB - of which 85 bytes was my main and call to printf. The rest is various bits and pieces dragged in my printf and related functions.

Comment: And to answer "why", maybe this: "Unlike other ports of GCC to Windows, the runtime libraries are not distributed using GNU's General Public License (GPL). You, therefore, do not have to distribute your source code with your programs unless, of course, you use a GPL library in your programs." is the answer. Quote from http://www.mingw.org/wiki/mingw